# why isn't my background-image url working (CSS)?

Tags: css, background-image

Here is my (relevant) css code:

```
li a {
  display: block;
  font-weight:bolder;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url('004.jpg')
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

I've tried the URL with double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes and it still isn't working. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks so much for your wise advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the url and the image extension are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. No quotes, and `background` instead of `background-image`. Also, make sure that the file path is correct.

```css
background: url(004.jpg);
```